# 'Edit this page to modify your web part content' code based webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

I have created a Webpart page and add the CEWP Webpart using Code like this

```
    <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Top" WebPartOrder="1">
        <![CDATA[
      <WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>display</Title>
  <FrameType>TitleBarOnly</FrameType>
  <Description>Ermöglicht Autoren die Eingabe von Rich-Text-Inhalt.</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>Top</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>0</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>false</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>false</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>false</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>false</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>false</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>false</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Dieses Webpart kann nicht importiert werden.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
  <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>
  <ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
  <Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
  <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
</WebPart>
      ]]>
    </AllUsersWebPart>
```

But after deploying.below the title, I am getting

> "'Edit this page to modify your web part Content"

I want to remove that. How can do ?.

thanks in advance.